# I want to replace the Mac OS with Ubuntu leaving Win 10 also bootable Intel dual boot Mac Pro Leopard)

Tags: dual-boot

Its a dual boot mac pro with Mac and Win 10 accessible. I want to totally remove the Mac Os leaving the Win 10 and/or Ubuntu bootable.
Older machine. A recover operation was tried by tech and was not successful. I may have to use the Windows OS to do the work of installing Ubuntu and deleting Mac OS.